Can I use DaSiamRPN tracker on Windows/ with Python 3.11
I am trying to integrate the DaSiamRPN Tracker into my code, but I wanted to see if this is possible first with my particular set up - I'm using python 3.11 on a windows computer (with a NVIDIA GPU).
Looking at the github for DaSiamRPN, it says recommends installing the following version of pytorch:
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.3.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl

(which is both for a different version of python and for a linux operating system). I want to find out a little more about the compatibility of this with the machine before I try to find a more appropriate version of pytorch. Any advice or recommendation would be greatly appreciated.
